# android GALAXY Note II auto rotation when using CAMERA INTENT

Tags: android

I am developing an Android Application that allows the user to take a photograph via an `Intent`
`android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.
I only require the photograph thumbnail so i do not pass any EXTRA's.
The activity within my application has two layout XML files, one for portrait the other landscape. I have tested on HTC and galaxy model phones (s3) and it works as designed.
When i test on a NOTE 2 however the photograph thumbnail is being lost due to the NOTE 2 "auto rotating" when i return from the camera back to my application. whatever orientation i have my application in the NOTE2 switches it to the opposite value on return from the Camera.
How can i stop this rotation? i am holding the note 2 in a fixed manner, why does it always rotate?